# Problem with Ganymed API

Tags: ssh, jsch, sshd

I am writing SSH Client code using Ganymed API's. When I am trying to execute a command remotely through my code it showing nothing and Program execution is not stopping. My putty giving correct output for same command. When I am issuing some basic commands it working fine. I am doing this in windows environment.

I also tried using JSCH API's. But it also giving me same behavior.

Can any one tell me what is wrong and any suggestions please.

Thanks,
Narendra

Comment: Still there? Your question is not really answerable in this form. We would need the Java code which is showing this behaviour, at least.

Answer (score 0):

set channel.connect() and session.disconnect in case of JSCH API's